# How should a controller be excluded on publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, release

I have a .NET MVC project that includes a UnitTest controller to run Jasmine tests against my JavaScript code. However, I don't want that to be available when I publish the site.

I'm thinking of a few ways to go about doing this, but I'm not sure what would be the best.

- Use Authorization attributes that are going to be introduced to forbid access to it
- Actually remove the Controller from the collection of available paths

I would be using the compiler directives for this (`#IF DEBUG`) to keep things separated easily. Honestly, I think that removing the controller would be the better option, but I'm not sure where that would go. Possibly the Global.cs file?

I would appreciate any suggestions. If forbidding access to the controller is the best solution, that's fine, and something that I can implement easily on my own. I just think there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just ignore the route conditionally:

```
#if !DEBUG
routes.IgnoreRoute("UnitTest/{*pathInfo}")
#endif
```

Though this is not much different than conditionally removing the controller itself as you suggested.

Comment: Really nice +1 from me too !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Web Deploy to publish, I think it will be a challenge to do it at that step since it's already in the assembly when it goes out for the publish.

But if you want it to be checked at runtime, as you stated. One way is to deny access to the controller in a production environment. Could use a web.config transform, or decorate the controller with an authorize attribute. Or even modify the routing somehow?

But you could modify the project file slightly. You can [include/exclude files depending on conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx). I would just add `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' "` to the `<Compile />` element which matched your controller class in the project file. Then when the project is built in release, the controller should be excluded. The only gotcha, it's a hidden configuration. If the controller was ever removed from the project, and readded, someone will need to remember to reapply the condition or it will end up in a publish.